# Create a timeline chart from json data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, html

I want to create a timeline chart from josn data. Time is in between 8.00 am and 6.00 pm.

chart style is in the attached image. [image: Chart image]

Here is the json data sample

```
var data = [{
    start: 0,
    duration: 15,
    title: "Exercise"
}, {
    start: 25,
    duration: 30,
    title: "Travel to work"
}, {
    start: 30,
    duration: 30,
    title: "Plan day"
}, {
    start: 60,
    duration: 15,
    title: "Review yesterday's commits"
}, {
    start: 100,
    duration: 15,
    title: "Code review"
}, {
    start: 180,
    duration: 90,
    title: "Have lunch with John"
}, {
    start: 360,
    duration: 30,
    title: "Skype call"
}, {
    start: 370,
    duration: 45,
    title: "Follow up with designer"
}, {
    start: 400,
    duration: 30,
    title: "Push up branch"
}
];
```

In the chart y axis have time from 8 to 6 showing at an interval of 30 min. Time taken to work / duration on each task is given as the width of each item. Values are aligned to left if the task starts from each hour or if the task starts from 30 min on each hour. Task starting in between are aligned to the center. That is if a task starts from 8.00 am, it starts from the beginning and if a task starts from 8.25 it is aligned to the center.

In the chart, first task starts from 8.00 so it is aligned to left.
second task starts at 8.25 so it is aligned to the center.
Third starts at 8.30 so it is aligned to the left.

IN json data, `start` denotes the starting time, that is 8.00 am, `duration` tells the duration. second item in json data, `start` is `25` means the task start at 8.25.

I was only able to show the time, i have no idea how to use the value from json and compare the time.

```
getTimeArray = () =>{
        var x = 30; //minutes interval
        var times = []; // time array
        var tt = 60*8; // start time
        var ap = ['AM', 'PM']; // AM-PM

        //loop to increment the time and push results in array
        for (var i=0;tt<19*60; i++) {
        var hh = Math.floor(tt/60); // getting hours of day in 0-24 format
        var mm = (tt%60); // getting minutes of the hour in 0-55 format
        times[i] = ("0" + (hh % 12)).slice(-2) + ':' + ("0" + mm).slice(-2); // pushing data in array in [00:00 - 12:00 AM/PM format]
        tt = tt + x;
        }
        return times;
    }
```

I use this function to get the time interval from 8 to 6. How do I use this value and json data value to get a graph like in the image.

Comment: You probably want to use a library such as [fullcalendar](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=001), [React Scheduler](https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/scheduler/docs/guides/getting-started/) etc.

Comment: @MoshFeu I already checked react scheduler, but its not what is needed. Thanks for the comment